# Passing textbox value to a sql statement

Tags: c#, sql

I am required to display data based on the value of two text boxes from one form to a methods form.

Below is my code to extract my two values which works fine:

```
txtfrom.Text = dtResults.Rows[0]["asset_open_per"].ToString();

this.txtto.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMM");
```

Now the that I have my two values, I will need these for a where clause in a sql statement, the sql statement is below:

```
public static DataTable GetPostings2(string AssetNumberV, string PeriodFromV, string PeriodToV)

        {

       DataTable dtGetPostings2;

        try

          {

           dtGetPostings2 = new DataTable("GetPostings");

   SqlParameter AssetNumber = new SqlParameter("@AssetNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar, 6);
   AssetNumber.Value = AssetNumberV;

   SqlParameter PeriodFrom = new SqlParameter("@PeriodFrom", SqlDbType.VarChar, 6);
   PeriodFrom.Value = txtfrom; 

   SqlParameter PeriodTo = new SqlParameter("@PeriodTo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 6);
   PeriodTo.Value = frmAsset.txtto; 

 SqlCommand scGetPostings2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [POSTING] WHERE [ASSET_NO] = @AssetNumber And PERIOD >= @PeriodFrom AND PERIOD <= @PeriodTo ORDER by PERIOD, JOUR_REF, JOUR_LINE", DataAccess.AssetConnection);

               scGetPostings2.Parameters.Add(AssetNumber);
               scGetPostings2.Parameters.Add(PeriodFrom);
               scGetPostings2.Parameters.Add(PeriodTo); 

               SqlDataAdapter sdaGetPostings2 = new SqlDataAdapter();
               sdaGetPostings2.SelectCommand = scGetPostings2;
               sdaGetPostings2.Fill(dtGetPostings2);

               return dtGetPostings2;
        }
```

There error I get is :

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'Assets.frmAssetPostings.txtto'

and same for the other texbox as well..

I have changed the properties of the text box to public etc, is there another solution in which this can be acheived.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to do SQL inside the form first then try do it from the app.cofig

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are already passing the values for the parameters inside your GetPostings2, why don't you use them instead of the textboxes of your frmAsset?

```
           scGetPostings2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AssetNumber", AssetNumberV); 
           scGetPostings2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PeriodFrom", PeriodFromV); 
           scGetPostings2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PeriodTo", PeriodToV);
```

By the way, you get the error because the GetPostings2 is a static method, inside this method you can't reference instance external objects like your frmAsset form.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Text property of the TextBoxes instead of trying to assign the TextBox object to our Sql Parameters.

```
SqlParameter AssetNumber = new SqlParameter("@AssetNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar, 6);     
AssetNumber.Value = AssetNumberV.Text;
```

Do the same for the rest of the TextBoxes you are reading values from.

Answer (score 0):

`this.txtto.Text` I assume is a Texbox but you are using it as  `PeriodTo.Value = frmAsset.txtto;`  in your GetPostings2 method

You will need to use it this way `frmAsset.txtto.Text; and frmAsset.txtfrom.Text;`