# c# sql "like" operation

Tags: c#, sql, sql-like

How can I replace the "@something" with the "textBox2.Text" , so the sql can search for things that contains it? This doesn't work.

```
private void cmd1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string content = null;
    FbConnection conn = new FbConnection(connectionString);
    conn.Open();
    FbCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();

    command.CommandText = @"select a.NAME, a.SCHOOL, a.CLASS
    from PEOPLE a, PLACES b
    where 
    b.KEY=a.PLACE and          
    a.SCHOOL like '%@something%'
    order by a.NAME";

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@something", textBox2.Text);
    FbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        content += (string)reader["NAME"] + "\r\n";
        textBox1.Text = content;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't add images of code, they add absolutely no value to your question.

Comment: you need to learn how to create concatenated string and how to use the `LIKE` statement you `LIKE "%" + value + "%"`

Comment: the other option is to do `'%' + @something + '%'` in the query.

Comment: @juharr absolutely.. this is what I was going to comment on / suggest as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing textbox value to a sql statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564011/passing-textbox-value-to-a-sql-statement)

Comment: Let's not suggest solutions that enable sql injection...

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 7):

By wrapping `@something` in single quotes in the SQL statement, you tell the database to treat it as a direct string value, so that search will be matching records to the actual "%@something%" string - with the logic for "%" parts, of course.

```
a.SCHOOL like @something

...

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@something", "%" + textBox2.Text + "%");
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on this site. It's kind of weird that a 13.2k reputation user does not know this

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Code answers that don't explain anything are discouraged. Self-explanatory code answers are okay. Whether this answer is self-explanatory is arguable, but personally, I'm leaning towards yes.

Comment: @hvd this is not self-explanatory. There's a difference in how the parameters are passed between the answer and the question, which actually solves the question, that should be explained.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto That's a legitimate point of view. The reason I disagreed (and again, I'm not saying it definitely was self-explanatory) was because the answer was stripped of anything not relevant to the few changes, and by looking only at those few changes, I felt the reason for those changes was or should be immediately obvious to anyone reading it. Regardless, I hope we can both agree that with the edits, it's a good answer, and a better answer than before :)

Answer (score 0):

Or use this solution.

```
command.CommandText = @"select a.NAME, a.SCHOOL, a.CLASS
from PEOPLE a, PLACES b
where 
b.KEY=a.PLACE and          
a.SCHOOL like '%' || @something || '%'
order by a.NAME";

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@something", textBox2.Text);
```

Like igor said `%@something%` is a string. You can make `@something` a 'variable' to and concatenate a `%` before and after it inside the SQL query.

**Update:** first used a `+` (Microsoft SQL Server) to concatenate it but @hvd said that firebird uses `||`. So I've changed it.

Comment: "The others use SQL injection" - @Igor's answer does not, and the other has been deleted

Comment: I know I was wrong indeed. Would answer to quick.

Comment: @RufusL Good point. In Microsoft SQL Server, `+` is used for string concatenation, and this answer does need string concatenation, but the OP's use of `FbConnection` suggests Firebird, which uses `||` for that.